# How to draw a round image with PDFsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I am using PDFsharp to make a PDF file, and have succeeded to put an image on my page.

```
        byte[] imgBytes = interview.Application.CandidateImage.ImageBinary.ToArray();
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(imgBytes);
        MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
        img.Save(strm, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        XImage xfoto = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(img);

        gfx.DrawImage(xfoto, 30, 130, 300, 300);
```

This gets the binary image data and the DrawImage will draw this image retrieved from the stream.

The thing is, I want to make the image round just as if I used img-circle class on HTML. Is there a function for this with PDFsharp? If not, how can I do this?

EDIT:

```
    void DrawClipPath(XGraphics gfx, PdfPage page)
    {


        XGraphicsPath path = new XGraphicsPath();
        path.AddEllipse((page.Width / 2) - 150, (page.Height / 2) - 120, 300, 300);
        gfx.Save();
        gfx.IntersectClip(path);

        // Draw a beam of dotted lines
        XPen pen = XPens.DarkRed.Clone();
        pen.DashStyle = XDashStyle.Dot;
        for (double r = 0; r <= 90; r += 0.5)
            gfx.DrawLine(pen, 0, 0, 250 * Math.Cos(r / 90 * Math.PI), 250 * Math.Sin(r / 90 * Math.PI));

        gfx.Restore();


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a circle as a clip path and then draw the image. You have to save the graphic state (XGraphics.Save) before setting the clip path and then restore it (XGraphics.Restore) after you drew all the objects that needed to be clipped.

EDIT: I'm not familiar with PDFSharp API but the code would look something like this:

```
gfx.Save();
XGraphicsPath clipPath = new XGraphicsPath();
clipPath.AddEllipse(30, 130, 300, 300);
gfx.IntersectClip(clipPath);
gfx.DrawImage(xfoto, 30, 130, 300, 300);
gfx.Restore();
```

Comment: I am not quite sure what a clip path does. Could you help me with a sample code?

Comment: Can you please look at my Edit? I did something like that following the example from the website. But the image stays the same. Could you correct my error?

Comment: @user7677413 see my edit, you restore the graphics after you have drawn the image (or any other objects you want clipped).

Answer (score 1):

You can use images with transparency so that only the round part in the centre is visible.

Or use a hack: draw the image first, then draw a white mask over the image, leaving just the round part in the centre showing.

Comment: That is actually smart. But I am not sure how to do the 2nd option in code. Could you help?

Comment: Look at the Graphics sample: http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx          The DrawPath sample with winding draws something with an Ellipse as a hole. There also is a DrawPolygon sample that uses Winding. I am not sure whether DrawPath is the most efficient way, but it would take about a dozen lines of code only.

Comment: so what we do is draw a square and make a transparent hole?

Comment: Yes, that's the trick: a square and a circle - using winding to have a transparent circle that leaves the photo visible.